# Should I override debhelper usage of the init system?

Tags: packaging, debian-based, debhelper

I am trying to build a debian package with systemd scripts and I don't really understand the best way to do it.

My first question is, should I use the `--with=systemd` option (and override `dh_systemd_enable` and `dh_systemd_start`) or is using `dh_installinit` with the `--name` option enough? Because both seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely need `--with=systemd` in your `dh` invocation.

As for which combination of overrides you need, it depends.

It sounds like you just need systemd units included, so you don't need to override anything.

Since your question doesn't have much context, I will list some of the use cases for when to override each systemd debhelpder.

**When to use override_dh_systemd_enable:**

- If you want to override your service to be *enabled* on a system that typically disables services on install (typically this is any linux flavor that *is not* derived from Debian)
- If you want to override your service to be *disabled* on a system that typically enables services on install (typically this is Debian or any linux flavor that *is* derived from Debian)
- If you have multiple systemd units in your Debian package, and you need to enable them
- If the main systemdunit in your debian package is named something other than *package-name.service* and it needs to be enabled/disabled

[Manual page for dh_systemd_enable](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_enable.1.en.html)

**When to use override_dh_systemd_start:**

- If you want to override your service to *NOT start on install or boot* on a system that typically starts services on install (typically this is Debian or any linux flavor that *is* derived from Debian)
- If you want the systemd unit to *not* stop or restart on debian package upgrade
- If you want the systemd unit to *not* stop until debian package upgrade is completed  (*This is useful for daemons that should not have a possibly long downtime during upgrade*)
- If you want to undo a *don't stop until debian package upgrade is completed* action
- If the main systemd unit in your debian package is named something other than *package-name.service* and any of the aforementioned actions above need to happen
- If you have multiple systemd units in your Debian package, and any of the aforementioned actions above need to happen

[Manual page for dh_systemd_start](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_start.1.en.html)

**When to use override_dh_installinit:**

- If the main systemd unit in your debian package is named something other than *package-name.service*
- If you have multiple systemd units in your Debian package, and you need to install them
- There are also many repeat functionalities that depend on what version of debhelper you are using that are similar to the ones listed in the `dh_systemd_start` and `dh_systemd_enable` section above. There are also many things that involve upstart, which is not relevant to this question. Please see the man page, linked below.

[Manual page for dh_installinit](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installinit.1.en.html)

Also note all these overrides go into your debian control file.

Comment: Note that nowadays it seems that dh_installsystemd is meant to be used instead of anything else.